# Excel to Tableau- formula conversion

Tags: excel, formula, tableau-api, calculated-field

Can someone please help me convert this Excel formula to a Tableau calculated field formula?

```
=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(FIND("-", [@[Replacement Policy]])>0, FALSE), TRUE, IF(ISBLANK([@[Original Inception Date]]), ([@[Replacement Policy Cleaned]]*1)>=4951472,[@[Original Inception Date]]>=DATE(2017,4,1))), TRUE)
```

I have gotten this far:

```
IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(FIND('-', [Replacement Policy]) >0 ))
then 'FALSE'  ELSEIF   'TRUE'  
then (ISBLANK([Original Inception Date]))
elseif  ([Replacement Policy Cleaned]*1)>=4951472
then  [Original Inception Date] >=DATE(2017,4,1) 
else 'true') end
```

Comment: Tableau does not have an IFERROR() function. What is that trying to do?

Comment: You likely want to return True and False without quotes - and once your logic is straight, can rewrite it just as a boolean expression without the outer IF

Comment: A simpler way to write a date literal is within # delimiters, as in #4/1/2017#

Comment: Multiplying by 1 doesn't seem useful and the CONTAINS() function will be a little simpler than using FIND() if you just want to know if there is a '-'- in a string

Answer (score 1):

Try to simplify to a boolean expression without nested logic. You don't need an enclosing if expression in that case.

Here is an example similar to your original. It evaluates to True if any of the subexpressions are true (OR logic).

```
not contains([Replacement Policy], '-') or
isnull([Original Inception Date]) or
[Replacement Policy Cleaned] < 4951472 or
[Original Inception Date] >= #4/1/2017#
```